# What prevents you declaring additional classes in a package, giving you access to package private members

Tags: java

If i create a project called `MyClassA` in a package `com/a/b/c`

defined as follows:

```
public class MyClassA {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

    String sayHi() {
        return "hi";
    }
}
```

If i export this project as a jar and create another project called `MyCassA` in a package `com/a/b/c` and import the jar i exported earlier, what is disallowing me from being able to see package protected method `sayHi()`?

I have tried this by deleting the first project i exported as a jar. When i tried this i get a compilation error that says the method is not visible.

Comment: Since it's package protected, if you're not in `com.a.b.c` then you won't see this method, so it's JRE that's disallowing you from doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answers telling you there is nothing that can prevent it are wrong.

You can [seal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/sealman.html) your package.  A sealed package is a package that may be defined in one and only one .jar file.  The Java runtime will reject any classes defined in that package outside of that .jar file.

Sealing a package is simple.  In the containing .jar file’s manifest, add a section for that package, and include a `Sealed: true` attribute:

```
Name: com/a/b/c
Sealed: true
```

Comment: And what prevents a user from repackaging in a different jar?

Comment: @GhostCat Nothing, as far as I know.  I got the impression that the question was about “growing” the package by adding classes to the classpath.

Comment: Nonetheless you got a good point. I updated my answer accordingly and send a vote your way.

Comment: @VGR this is s very helpful! Thank you for sharing this.

Answer (score 1):

Not much. Whilst you are not using Java9, with [module](https://www.journaldev.com/13106/java-9-modules) support enabled.

It is no problem to sneak into existing packages by simply "faking" them. As the other answer outlines you can seal a package via meta data within a jar file. And when you further on think about signing jar files a certain degree of seems to be possible. But I guess even then there might be tricks using class loader magic.

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8 or lower, nothing will disallow you to do that. In other words, it is allowed.

In Java 9, the module system will enforce that packages can only be in a single module

Comment: I can't actually use the package protected method. Keep in mind these are two different projects. I have tried this and it says that the method is not visible

Comment: To be more clear, after exporting the first project, i deleted it and created a new project with the same name file name package name

Comment: Are you then **sure** that the setup of your new project is so that it sees the JAR with the "old" content *first* in the classpath? As I have written almost at the same time: when your setup is "correct", it should be no problem doing what you intend to do.

Comment: What is giving you the error? An IDE? Javac? Did you properly load the jar file you exported? With the information we currently have, it could be anything.

Comment: So I just tried it again. I guess i did it wrong the first time.... this is crazy...had no idea you could do this

Comment: Thank-you by the way